# Multiple series of data in Highcharts but second line graph is displayed squashed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I'm pretty new in using Highcharts API and, just started to embark using its cool features.  I have a ASP.NET MVC web application which plot a line graph from a data source.  In my application a user selects a key value from a list box and, out of that key an array of values will be retrieved and used the data as series for the graph.

[Chart 1] This is the plotted highchart.[image]

[Chart 2] This is the expected output[image]

As you can see in the above screenshots, CDT158 series displayed the graph correctly, more similar to Chart 2.  But, Series 2 in Chart 1 is squashed, it is supposed to be like in Chart 2 - SINUSOID.

This is my functions that prepares and display the chart

```
var myChart;
function prepareChartData(dataChart)
{
    var xAxis = [];
    var dataSeries = [];
    var xTitle;

    for (var i = 0; i < dataChart.length; i++) {
        var items = dataChart[i];
        var XcategoriesItem = moment(items.Time).format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
        var seriesData = parseFloat(items.Value);

        xAxis.push(XcategoriesItem);
        dataSeries.push(seriesData);

        xTitle = items.Name;
    }

    if (myChart == undefined)
    {
        plotChartData(xAxis, dataSeries, xTitle);
        return;
    }

    myChart.addSeries({
        title: xTitle,
        data: dataSeries
    });
};

    function plotChartData(Xaxis, dataseries, xtitle)
{
    myChart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'svgtrendspace',
            type: 'line',
            zoomType: 'xy',
            panning: true,
            panKey: 'shift',
            plotBorderWidth: 1
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Sample Chart'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'horizontal',
            align: 'bottom',
            horizontalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false,
                    format: '{y}'
                },
                allowPointSelect: false
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category',
            categories: Xaxis,
            labels: {
                rotation: -65,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '8px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                }
            },
            tickInterval: 60
        },
        yAxis: {
            gridLineColor: '#DDDDDD',
            gridLineWidth: 0.5
        },
        series: [{
            name: xtitle,
            data: dataseries,
            //name: '',
            //data: [],
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>',
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }]
    });
};
```

This is the div element that displays the chart
`<div id="svgtrendspace" style="overflow:auto;display:table-row; height:100%;"></div>`

The jquery post function that retrieves data from AE controller.

```
$.post("/AE/UpdateTrend", { TrendRequestData: jdata },
    function (data) {
        if (data.length > 4) {
            var results = $.parseJSON(data);

            console.log(results);

            prepareChartData(results);
            trendData = results;
        }
        else {
            trendData = "";
            FillNoData("#svgtrendspace");

            $('#MinimumHorizontalLine').val("");
            $('#MaximumHorizontalLine').val("");
        }
    });
```

What could go wrong in my highcharts configuration that made the second series line graph squashed?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's caused by using categories, but actually you want to use datetime axis. Categories for first series and the second one don't match and that's the result. In other words, I would:

1. Change data format for array of points:

   ```
   for (var i = 0; i < dataChart.length; i++) {
     var items = dataChart[i];
     var xDate = +moment(items.Time);
     var seriesData = parseFloat(items.Value);

     dataSeries.push([xDate, seriesData]);

     xTitle = items.Name;
   }
   ```
2. Change type to `"datetime"` and remove categories:

   ```
   xAxis: {
       type: 'datetime', // type
       // categories: Xaxis, // remove
       labels: {
           rotation: -65,
           style: {
               fontSize: '8px',
               fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
           }
       },
       // tickInterval: 60 // remove that too - you don't want ticks every 60 milliseconds ;) 
   },
   ```

Comment: thanks for your answer.  You are right, the data format for my points aren't matched with the second line graph.  The second line graph is now correctly displayed (not squashed) after I changed type to `datetime` and removed `categories`.  One issue remaining is that, the label Series 2 doesn't appear as SINUSOID where it should be.  But it's picking up the `xTitle`, what could go wrong?

Comment: Just a guess but what is `title` in `addSeries()` options? ;) There should be `name`.

Comment: my mistake, `title` is not the correct property for `addSeries()` options.  You are right again, it should be `name`.  Thank you for looking into that. :)